# What can make a functionality run a simulator and not on the device?

Tags: react-native, charts, ios-simulator, react-native-chart-kit

I'm building an app using React Native.
I'm fetching an array of values fetched from a database in order to provide users a line chart which refresh every X seconds ( 3s atm ).
This works fine on iOS simulator but when it comes to deploy to TestFlight, and run the app on a device, the curves are not displayed, nothing happens.
Since I can use some other feature that requires to fetch data from the DB, I figured out that the issue was not from the API requests.
I currently use *react-native-chart-kit*, but I tried with *react-native-svg-charts* as well, the issue remains the same.

Any hint ?

The issue is the same when I display the array of the fetched values, a new value appears on the simulator every 3 seconds but it does not show anything on the device.

Comment: There’s not enough here to diagnose what’s going on, but confirm that the problem is really device v simulator and not “running while attached to debugger” vs “running when not attached to debugger”. If you install the app from Xcode (but don’t run it from Xcode, just build and install) and then run it stand-alone on the device, does it work? If you do the same on the simulator, what do you experience?

Comment: By the way, when you say “every X seconds”, is this while the app is running in the foreground, or in the background?

Comment: I guess it's not enough but I didn't even know what piece of information to provide . I'm not quite sure to understand your question. All I do with Xcode is to create the Build and then deploy it to Testflight. I never install it from Xcode, I only upload Build once it's done. The app requests the Api, every 3 seconds , when the user is on the view that shows the feature. So that the curves feels like a kind of live stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue.

The issue were spotted at the API request.
My request takes 2 timestamp params : start time / end time

I always debug the app using the browser and launch ios sim from the RN project.

This time I tried to Run a the project from Xcode and edit the Scheme as release instead of debug .

When I checked the console from Xcode I noticed that my Start time timestamp when considered as 'NaN'.. Not the End time timestamp.

Back to the RN project and to the browser console, the timestamp is alright.

I made some random changes and now it works fine .

Here's what I had before solving the issue:

```
function formatDate(rawStamp) {
        const now = new Date(rawStamp);
        var convertToStr =
            now.getFullYear() +
            "-" +
            ("00" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
            "-" +
            ("00" + now.getDate()).slice(-2) +
            " " +
            ("00" + now.getHours()).slice(-2) +
            ":" +
            ("00" + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
            ":" +
            ("00" + now.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

   
           return convertToStr
   }

   const nowStr = formatDate(Date.now() - 7200000) 
   const gameStampMinusX = Date.parse(nowStr) - (300000) 
   const gameStampMinusXToStr = formatDate(gameStampMinusX)
```

Here's what solved the issue:

```
   const nowStr = formatDate(Date.now() - 7200000)
   const gameStampMinusX = Date.now() - 7200000 - 300000
   const gameStampMinusXToStr = formatDate(gameStampMinusX)
```

I'm a newbie so I cannot explain this behavior, but seems that this little change makes Xcode recognize the timestamp, and proceed the the API request correctly.

If anyone can explain, feel free !